# Getting error when using local amplify mock api: The request has a 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id' HTTP header which is reserved for AWS X-Ray trace header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-amplify, aws-xray

I am currently using Amplify to set up my backend because Appsync is a key part of my stack.

However, I also use SQS to publish certain messages into a queue. This is easily done using the in-code editor of lambda but since I'm running lambda functions locally now, I am unable to send messages to the queue now with the following error:

InvalidParameterValue: The request has a 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id' HTTP header which is reserved for AWS X-Ray trace header and has an invalid value 'amplify-mock-x-amzn-trace-id'

This is my code to send messages into the queue.

response = await sqs.sendMessageBatch(slackParams).promise().catch(async (err) => {
console.log(`response from sqs: ${err}`);
});

Once I do amplify push, the code works fine on the cloud lambda but the issue comes only when I do amplify mock api. (During local testing, I am unable to add to the queue)

Is there any way I can mock my SQS setup locally as well? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you run locally, you can add a valid trace id to the headers through the environment variables with something like `process.env._X_AMZN_TRACE_ID = 'Root=1-63b6ffe7-2c48b4e36086hhhf21d16c8c;Parent=51740oo32a9d2e68;Sampled=0'` and it should stop bothering you. Definitely a bug on Amazon's part that they would autopopulate this header with an invalid value, but it seems like if you pass in any valid `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` it will work. I added a line to my function to print the trace Id, ran it on the cloud, and checked the logs to get a valid id. Maybe the suggested code above will work for you, but you might have to run on the cloud to get an id yourself.